# Google gmail API: base64 needs bytes but URL body needs str

Tags: python, json, google-api, base64

I am working through this [Google Gmail API tutorial](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/sending?authuser=2#python_2) (really I am skimming it to send an email).
The body of my email must be encoded MIMEText & base64 but the contents of 'raw' property of a JSON payload must be a string. This leads me to a 'rock in a hard place' with 2 errors. Here is the code following the tutorial:

```
message = MIMEText(RecipData["EmailText"])

message['to'] = RecipData["Email"]

message['from'] = SENDER

message['subject'] = Subject

EncodedMessage = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}

service.users().messages().send(userId=SENDER, body=EncodedMessage).execute()
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

Now if I change this line:

```
EncodedMessage = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_string())}
```

To:

```
EncodedMessage = {'raw': base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes())}
```

Then I get an error of:

```
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Not sure what I should do to get around this? Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here what I ended up doing. I converted the MIMEText to a byte so that it would work inside `base64.urlsafe_b64encode()` then I used `str()` so the data would fit into JSON. But, the `str()` needed to be stripped of is `b'...'` which was wrapped into the string.

```
message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(bytes(message))

message = {'raw': str(message).strip('b').strip('\'')}
print(service.users().messages().send(userId="me", body=message).execute())
```